# Bootstrap 5 Dynamic Accordion looking to only have a single header

Tags: php, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and when I attempt to input data into the accordion it outputs a new header as Drops for every single data that is filled into the body. I'm looking to have just one header for every listing within that database column.

```
<div class="accordion">

          <?php
          $i = 1;
          $recipes = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM recipe WHERE category = 'Drops' ORDER BY name ASC;";
          $recipe_run = mysqli_query($conn, $recipes);
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($recipe_run) ) {
          ?>

          <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne<?= $i ?>">
              <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne<?= $i ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne<?= $i ?>">
                <!--  Title  -->
                Drops
              </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="collapseOne<?= $i ?>" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne<?= $i ?>">
              <div class="accordion-body">
                <!-- Contents  -->
                <?=$row['name'];?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <?php
          $i++;
          }
          ?>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Sure, you can move your while loop to the place where there currently is just `<?=$row['name'];?>` - but then you would be creating only one single collapsible element. Is that what you actually want?

Comment: I do want just one collapsible element but there are multiple contents within the $row['name] when putting my while loop above that in the code it does display each content but only the first one is displayed under the collapsible button. I want it to collapse and show eg.

Header: Drops
Content:
Flavor1
Flavor2
Flavor3
etc.

Comment: So you want the _button_ to show all of the names as well? Then you need to output them inside the button, too.

Comment: I only want the button to say "Drops" then under the button once clicked a list of each content

Comment: And where did you place the loop now - _inside_ `<div class="accordion-body">`?

Comment: That is where it is currently, I tried moving it above `<?=$row['name'];?>`  and it output one of the database column contents below the button but the rest fell outside of the accordion.

Comment: _"I tried moving it above `<?=$row['name'];?>`"_ - well below would not make any sense to begin with, because $row only gets set _by_ the loop. Can you please add the current code in that place to the end of your question?

Comment: Added current code to the question

Comment: You are _closing_ `<div class="accordion-body">` inside of your loop, this of course needs to happen outside of it, _after_.

Comment: Oh god you're right what a dumb mistake, Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One heading with multiple contents

Credit to **CBroe** for the help

```
<div class="accordion">

          <?php
          $i = 1;
          $recipes = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM recipe WHERE category = 'Drops' ORDER BY name ASC;";
          $recipe_run = mysqli_query($conn, $recipes);
          ?>

          <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne<?= $i ?>">
              <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne<?= $i ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne<?= $i ?>">
                <!--  Title  -->
                Drops
              </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="collapseOne<?= $i ?>" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne<?= $i ?>">
              <div class="accordion-body">
                <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($recipe_run) ) { ?>
                <!-- Contents  -->
                <?=$row['name'];?>

                <?php
                  $i++;
                  }
                ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```